# C# Extracting a name from a string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I want to extract 'James\, Brown' from the string below but I don't always know what the name will be. The comma is causing me some difficuly so what would you suggest to extract James\, Brown?

OU=James\, Brown,OU=Test,DC=Internal,DC=Net

Thanks

Comment: Too bad you can't get the API you're using to give you the output in a structured format.  Parsing is tiresome.

Answer (score 8):

A regex is likely your best approach

```
static string ParseName(string arg) {
    var regex = new Regex(@"^OU=([a-zA-Z\\]+\,\s+[a-zA-Z\\]+)\,.*$");
    var match = regex.Match(arg);
    return match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Comment: A good approach, but one of which I have an irrational fear.  :)

Comment: But in order to do that, I must admit that my fear is wrong, and as a Yorkshireman, I am *never* wrong. ;-)

Comment: You're assuming every name has a comma in it which might be wrong (and probably is).

Comment: @David, questioner didn't mention it one way or the other so all I can go on is what they put in the question.  I could also wonder if @'s are allowed in the name.  Or perhaps 3 name vs. 2.  But once again unless the asker puts it in their question assumptions are necessary.

Comment: @Jared: I'm just pointing at a potential error that might appear in production code 2 years from now ;-). Still the sample provided looks really like an LDAP DN which is why I prefer Mark Brackett's answer.

Comment: @David, your comment though is also based on an assumption.  You assume that Mark is correct (almost certainly is).  2 years from now you might find out they invented their own naming standard.  Without clarification from the user there is no way to give 100% correct answers.

Comment: What about the Regexp: "OU=(?<OUName>[^,]+)" ? Then use match.Groups["OUName"].Value, Doesn't assume OU at the start of the string, matches everything into the OU except comma (or end of line).

Answer (score 4):

You can use a regex:

```
string input = @"OU=James\, Brown,OU=Test,DC=Internal,DC=Net";
Match m = Regex.Match(input, "^OU=(.*?),OU=.*$");
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

A quite brittle way to do this might be...

```
string name = @"OU=James\, Brown,OU=Test,DC=Internal,DC=Net";
string[] splitUp = name.Split("=".ToCharArray(),3);
string namePart = splitUp[1].Replace(",OU","");
Console.WriteLine(namePart);
```

I wouldn't necessarily advocate this method, but I've just come back from a departmental Christmas lyunch and my brain is not fully engaged yet.

Comment: Hi, my name is "Foo,OUBar" but you can call me "FooBar" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd start off with a regex to split up the groups:

```
    Regex rx = new Regex(@"(?<!\\),");
    String test = "OU=James\\, Brown,OU=Test,DC=Internal,DC=Net";
    String[] segments = rx.Split(test);
```

But from there I would split up the parameters in the array by splitting them up manually, so that you don't have to use a regex that depends on more than the separator character used. Since this looks like an LDAP query, it might not matter if you always look at params[0], but there is a chance that the name might be set as "CN=". You can cover both cases by just reading the query like this:

```
    String name = segments[0].Split('=', 2)[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

That looks suspiciously like an LDAP or Active Directory distinguished name formatted according to [RFC 2253](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2253.txt)/[4514](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4514.txt).

Unless you're working with well known names and/or are okay with a fragile hackaround (like the regex solutions) - then you should start by reading the spec.

If you, like me, generally hate implementing code according to RFCs - then hope [this guy](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/dnparser.aspx) did a better job following the spec than you would. At least he *claims* to be 2253 compliant.

Answer (score 0):

If the format is always the same:

```
string line = GetStringFromWherever();

int start = line.IndexOf("=") + 1;//+1 to get start of name
int end = line.IndexOf("OU=",start) -1; //-1 to remove comma

string name = line.Substring(start, end - start);
```

Forgive if syntax is not quite right - from memory. Obviously this is not very robust and fails if the format ever changes.

Comment: Actually, the second parameter of SubString is length, not endIndex. In your example it SHOULD be name = line.SubString(start, end - start). I've always hated that about Substring, which is the reason why I've created extension methods that DO allow startIndex and endIndex.

Comment: xan - I edited to correct syntax, since I am in front of a machine with Snippetcompiler installed.  :)

Answer (score 0):

If the slash is always there, I would look at potentially using RegEx to do the match, you can use a match group for the last and first names.

^OU=([a-zA-Z]*)\,\s([a-zA-Z]*)

That RegEx will match names that include characters only, you will need to refine it a bit for better matching for the non-standard names.  [Here is a RegEx tester](http://www.iowacomputergurus.com/free-products/regular-expression-tester.aspx) to help you along the way if you go this route.

Answer (score 0):

Replace \, with your own preferred magic string (perhaps & #44;), split on remaining commas or search til the first comma, then replace your magic string with a single comma.

i.e. Something like:

```
string originalStr = @"OU=James\, Brown,OU=Test,DC=Internal,DC=Net";
string replacedStr = originalStr.Replace("\,", "&#44;");

string name = replacedStr.Substring(0, replacedStr.IndexOf(","));
Console.WriteLine(name.Replace("&#44;", ","));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running in Windows, use PInvoke with [`DsUnquoteRdnValueW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676054(v=vs.85).aspx).  For code, see my answer to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11091804/628981