# Extract Common Name from Distinguished Name

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, ldap, x509

Is there a call in .NET that parses the CN from a rfc-2253 encoded distinguished name? I know there are some third-party libraries that do this, but I would prefer to use native .NET libraries if possible.

Examples of a string encoded DN

> CN=L. Eagle,O=Sue\, Grabbit and Runn,C=GB
>
> CN=Jeff Smith,OU=Sales,DC=Fabrikam,DC=COM

Comment: You might want to add LDAP to the list of tags on your question. Also, search SO for [LDAP C#]. There might be a related question.

Comment: See https://pscx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Trunk/Src/Pscx.UnitTests/DirectoryServices/DirectoryServicesTest.cs for code used in the Powershell Community Extensions

Comment: https://pscx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Trunk/Src/Pscx.UnitTests/DirectoryServices/DirectoryServicesTest.cs not found

Answer (score 20):

If you are working with an `X509Certificate2`, there is a method that you can use to extract the Simple Name. The Simple Name is equivalent to the Common Name RDN within the Subject field of the main certificate:

```
x5092Cert.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.SimpleName, false);
```

Alternatively, `X509NameType.DnsName` can be used to retrieve the Subject Alternative Name, if present; otherwise, it will default to the Common Name:

```
x5092Cert.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.DnsName, false);
```

Comment: In case certificate has Subject Alternative Name, DnsName will return value of it. For example, alt name is `DNS Name=prog.org`, this method will return `prog.org`

Comment: @PylypLebediev This is true. More reliably, `X509NameType.SimpleName` can be used for the CN.

Answer (score 9):

After digging around in the .NET source code it looks like there is an internal utility class that can parse Distinguished Names  into their different components. Unfortunately the utility class is not made public, but you can access it using reflection:

```
string dn = "CN=TestGroup,OU=Groups,OU=UT-SLC,OU=US,DC=Company,DC=com";
Assembly dirsvc = Assembly.Load("System.DirectoryServices");
Type asmType = dirsvc.GetType("System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Utils");
MethodInfo mi = asmType.GetMethod("GetDNComponents", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
string[] parameters = { dn };
var test = mi.Invoke(null, parameters);
//test.Dump("test1");//shows details when using Linqpad 

//Convert Distinguished Name (DN) to Relative Distinguished Names (RDN) 
MethodInfo mi2 = asmType.GetMethod("GetRdnFromDN", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
var test2 = mi2.Invoke(null, parameters);
//test2.Dump("test2");//shows details when using Linqpad
```

The results would look like this:

```
//test1 is array of internal "Component" struct that has name/values as strings
Name   Value 
CN     TestGroup 
OU     Groups 
OU     UT-SLC
OU     US 
DC     company 
DC     com 


//test2 is a string with CN=RDN 
CN=TestGroup
```

Please not this is an internal utility class and could change in a future release.

Comment: Worked great until I needed to parse mult-valued RDNs. for example ```cn=Robert Smith+uid=rsmith,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com```. This fails with "The specified distinguished name has an invalid format".

Comment: Code for the `GetDNComponents` is here: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/c539d6c627b169d45f0b4cf1826b560cd0862abe/src/System.DirectoryServices/src/System/DirectoryServices/ActiveDirectory/Utils.cs#L440-L449

Comment: Dump in unit test (MSTest) ?

Comment: type `System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Component[]` is internal. `Console.WriteLine("Tipo: " + test.GetType().FullName);`

Answer (score 7):

I had the same question, myself, when I found yours. Didn't find anything in the BCL; however, I did stumble across this CodeProject article that hit the nail squarely on the head.

I hope it helps you out, too.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9788/An-RFC-2253-Compliant-Distinguished-Name-Parser

Comment: I just released it as a NuGet package here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/DNParser/ (just to be clear: I'm not the author, but I love NuGet packages).

Answer (score 6):

If you are on Windows, [@MaxKiselev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60739796/138200) works perfectly.  On non-Windows platforms, it returns the ASN1 dumps of each attribute.

.Net Core 5+ includes an ASN1 parser, so you can access the RDN's in a cross-platform manner by using `AsnReader`.

Helper class:

```
public static class X509DistinguishedNameExtensions
{ 
    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetRelativeNames(this X500DistinguishedName dn)
    {
        var reader = new AsnReader(dn.RawData, AsnEncodingRules.BER);
        var snSeq = reader.ReadSequence();
        if (!snSeq.HasData)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        // Many types are allowable.  We're only going to support the string-like ones
        // (This excludes IPAddress, X400 address, and other wierd stuff)
        // https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#page-37
        // https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#page-112
        var allowedRdnTags = new[]
        {
            UniversalTagNumber.TeletexString, UniversalTagNumber.PrintableString,
            UniversalTagNumber.UniversalString, UniversalTagNumber.UTF8String,
            UniversalTagNumber.BMPString, UniversalTagNumber.IA5String,
            UniversalTagNumber.NumericString, UniversalTagNumber.VisibleString,
            UniversalTagNumber.T61String
        };
        while (snSeq.HasData)
        {
            var rdnSeq = snSeq.ReadSetOf().ReadSequence();
            var attrOid = rdnSeq.ReadObjectIdentifier();
            var attrValueTagNo = (UniversalTagNumber)rdnSeq.PeekTag().TagValue;
            if (!allowedRdnTags.Contains(attrValueTagNo))
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException($"Unknown tag type {attrValueTagNo} for attr {attrOid}");
            }
            var attrValue = rdnSeq.ReadCharacterString(attrValueTagNo);
            var friendlyName = new Oid(attrOid).FriendlyName;
            yield return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(friendlyName ?? attrOid, attrValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
// Subject: CN=Example, O=Organization
var cert = new X509Certificate2("foo.cer");
var names = this.cert.SubjectName.GetRelativeNames().ToArray();
// names has [ { "CN": "Example" }, { "O": "Organization" } ]
```

Since this does not involve any string parsing, no escape or injections can be mishandled.  It doesn't support decoding DN's that contain non-string elements, but those seem exceedingly rare.

Comment: Works successfully in Windows and in Ubuntu 22.04 in .NET 6. Looks like the best way to parse a DN using Native libraries to get CN or other components.

Answer (score 5):

Do Win32 functions count?  You can use PInvoke with [`DsGetRdnW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675991(v=vs.85).aspx).  For code, see my answer to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11091804/628981.

Answer (score 5):

You can extract the common name from an ASN.1-encoded distinguished name using AsnEncodedData class:

```c#
var distinguishedName= new X500DistinguishedName("CN=TestGroup,OU=Groups,OU=UT-SLC,OU=US,DC=Company,DC=com");
var commonNameData = new AsnEncodedData("CN", distinguishedName.RawData);
var commonName = commonNameData.Format(false);
```

A downside of this approach is that if you specify an unrecognized OID or the field identified with the OID is missing in the distinguished name, `Format` method will return a hex string with the encoded value of full distinguished name so you may want to verify the result.

Also the documentation does not seem to specify if the rawData parameter of the AsnEncodedData constructor is allowed to contain other OIDs besides the one specified as the first argument so it may break on non-Windows OS or in a future version of .NET Framework.

Comment: This is indeed broken on non-windows platforms.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71376270/138200 for a version which uses the new ASN1 parser to replace the functionality of `AsnEncodedData`

Answer (score 2):

Just adding my two cents here. This implementation works "best" if you first learn what business rules are in place that will ultimately dictate *how much* of the RFC will ever be implemented at your company.

```
private static string ExtractCN(string distinguishedName)
{
    // CN=...,OU=...,OU=...,DC=...,DC=...
    string[] parts;

    parts = distinguishedName.Split(new[] { ",DC=" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    var dc = parts.Skip(1);

    parts = parts[0].Split(new[] { ",OU=" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    var ou = parts.Skip(1);

    parts = parts[0].Split(new[] { ",CN=" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    var cnMulti = parts.Skip(1);

    var cn = parts[0];

    if (!Regex.IsMatch(cn, "^CN="))
        throw new CustomException(string.Format("Unable to parse distinguishedName for commonName ({0})", distinguishedName));

    return Regex.Replace(cn, "^CN=", string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: Samples ***CN, CN, OU***: `CN=Usuarios del dominio,CN=Users,DC=company,DC=es`
            ,  `CN=PRE_VPN_Usuarios,CN=Users,OU=PREPRODUCCION,DC=company,DC=es`
            , `CN=PRE_Usuarios COMUNICADOS MAD,CN=Users,OU=PREPRODUCCION,DC=company,DC=es`
           , `CN=PRE_Campaña TELEFONICA Agentes MAD,OU=TELEFONICA,OU=CAMPAÑAS,OU=PREPRODUCCION,DC=company,DC=es`

Comment: In my experience "how much of the RFC will ever be implemented at your company" is never a hard and fast rule. At some point your code will fail because someone used a valid CN which your code doesn't handle. There is no getting around the need to handle the entire RFC.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one:

```
string cnPattern = @"^CN=(?<cn>.+?)(?<!\\),";
string dn        = @"CN=Doe\, John,OU=My OU,DC=domain,DC=com";

Regex re = new Regex(cnPattern);          
Match m  = re.Match(dn);

if (m.Success)
{
  // Item with index 1 returns the first group match.
  string cn = m.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Adapted from [Powershell Regular Expression for Extracting Parts of an Active Directory Distiniguished Name](http://www.powershellish.com/blog/2015/01/21/regex-dn/).

Comment: There are problems with this regex: the CN isn't guaranteed to be at the start of the DN, you assume that there will be a name part *after the* CN, and it doesn't handle quoted strings. Example DN: `O=Acme, OU=Acme, CN="My super, ""Great"" CN"`

Comment: Why wouldn't CN be in the beginning? Who told you CN can be in the middle? In your example, comma must be escaped, just as the quotation characters. Quotes are not used in DN to isolate DN part values.

Comment: Check section 4 of RFC2253 - it states that implementations must allow values to be surrounded by quotes, and inside those quotes commas do not need to be escaped

Comment: Forgot to answer about the CN position - I'm going by experience of what I've seen in real life. You can also see examples of this in [this](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.501-199311-S/en) document and [this](https://tech.labs.oliverwyman.com/blog/2007/10/30/whats-in-a-distinguished-name/) page

Comment: Samples ***CN, CN, OU***: `CN=Usuarios del dominio,CN=Users,DC=company,DC=es`
            ,  `CN=PRE_VPN_Usuarios,CN=Users,OU=PREPRODUCCION,DC=company,DC=es`
            , `CN=PRE_Usuarios COMUNICADOS MAD,CN=Users,OU=PREPRODUCCION,DC=company,DC=es`
           , `CN=PRE_Campaña TELEFONICA Agentes MAD,OU=TELEFONICA,OU=CAMPAÑAS,OU=PREPRODUCCION,DC=company,DC=es`

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions to do this. Here's a regex pattern than can parse the whole DN, then you can just take the parts you are interested in:

`(?:^|,\s?)(?:(?<name>[A-Z]+)=(?<val>"(?:[^"]|"")+"|(?:\\,|[^,])+))+`

Here it is formatted a bit nicer, and with some comments:

```
(?:^|,\s?)               <-- Start or a comma
(?:
    (?<name>[A-Z]+)
    =
    (?<val>
        "(?:[^"]|"")+"   <-- Quoted strings
        |
        (?:\\,|[^,])+    <-- Unquoted strings
    )
)+
```

This regex will give you `name` and `val` capture groups for each match.

DN strings can optionally be quoted (e.g. `"Hello"`, which allows them to contain  unescaped commas. Alternatively, if not quoted, commas must be escaped with a backslash (e.g. `Hello\, there!`). This regex handles both quoted and unquoted strings.

Here's a link so you can see it in action: https://regex101.com/r/7vhdDz/1

Comment: I've find out this one very good to check format to any given DN; it works very well... only downside is you need to build your self a validation method, to be sure that all "xx=zz" attributes are  within supported rules, but beside that I really like this one... and best I can use it in Python. Thanks!

Comment: Samples: `CN=Usuarios del dominio,CN=Users,DC=company,DC=es`
            ,  `CN=PRE_VPN_Usuarios,CN=Users,OU=PREPRODUCCION,DC=company,DC=es`
            , `CN=PRE_Usuarios COMUNICADOS MAD,CN=Users,OU=PREPRODUCCION,DC=company,DC=es`
           , `CN=PRE_Campaña TELEFONICA Agentes MAD,OU=TELEFONICA,OU=CAMPAÑAS,OU=PREPRODUCCION,DC=company,DC=es`

Comment: @Kiquenet the regex seems to work just fine with those samples?

Answer (score 1):

If the order is uncertain, I do this:

```
private static string ExtractCN(string dn)
{
    string[] parts = dn.Split(new char[] { ',' });

    for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
    {
        var p = parts[i];
        var elems = p.Split(new char[] { '=' });
        var t = elems[0].Trim().ToUpper();
        var v = elems[1].Trim();
        if (t == "CN")
        {
            return v;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Common names containing commas will break this. Example: `CN=Martin Luther King\, Jr.` will incorrectly return `Martin Luther King`

Answer (score 1):

This is my almost RFC-compliant fail-safe DN parser derived from https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9788/An-RFC-2253-Compliant-Distinguished-Name-Parser and an example of its usage (extract subject name as CN and O, both optional, concatenated with comma):

```
    private static string GetCertificateString(X509Certificate2 certificate)
    {
        var subjectComponents = certificate.Subject.ParseDistinguishedName();
        var subjectName = string.Join(", ", subjectComponents
            .Where(m => (m.Item1 == "CN") || (m.Item1 == "O"))
            .Select(n => n.Item2)
            .Distinct());

        return $"{certificate.SerialNumber} {certificate.NotBefore:yyyy.MM.dd}-{certificate.NotAfter:yyyy.MM.dd} {subjectName}";
    }

    private enum DistinguishedNameParserState
    {
        Component,
        QuotedString,
        EscapedCharacter,
    };

    public static IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>> ParseDistinguishedName(this string value)
    {
        var previousState = DistinguishedNameParserState.Component;
        var currentState = DistinguishedNameParserState.Component;
        var currentComponent = new StringBuilder();
        var previousChar = char.MinValue;
        var position = 0;

        Func<StringBuilder, Tuple<string, string>> parseComponent = sb =>
        {
            var s = sb.ToString();
            sb.Clear();

            var index = s.IndexOf('=');
            if (index == -1)
            {
                return null;
            }

            var item1 = s.Substring(0, index).Trim().ToUpper();
            var item2 = s.Substring(index + 1).Trim();

            return Tuple.Create(item1, item2);
        };

        while (position < value.Length)
        {
            var currentChar = value[position];

            switch (currentState)
            {
                case DistinguishedNameParserState.Component:
                    switch (currentChar)
                    {
                        case ',':
                        case ';':
                            // Separator found, yield parsed component
                            var component = parseComponent(currentComponent);
                            if (component != null)
                            {
                                yield return component;
                            }
                            break;

                        case '\\':
                            // Escape character found
                            previousState = currentState;
                            currentState = DistinguishedNameParserState.EscapedCharacter;
                            break;

                        case '"':
                            // Quotation mark found
                            if (previousChar == currentChar)
                            {
                                // Double quotes inside quoted string produce single quote
                                currentComponent.Append(currentChar);
                            }
                            currentState = DistinguishedNameParserState.QuotedString;
                            break;

                        default:
                            currentComponent.Append(currentChar);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;

                case DistinguishedNameParserState.QuotedString:
                    switch (currentChar)
                    {
                        case '\\':
                            // Escape character found
                            previousState = currentState;
                            currentState = DistinguishedNameParserState.EscapedCharacter;
                            break;

                        case '"':
                            // Quotation mark found
                            currentState = DistinguishedNameParserState.Component;
                            break;

                        default:
                            currentComponent.Append(currentChar);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;

                case DistinguishedNameParserState.EscapedCharacter:
                    currentComponent.Append(currentChar);
                    currentState = previousState;
                    currentChar = char.MinValue;
                    break;
            }

            previousChar = currentChar;
            position++;
        }

        // Yield last parsed component, if any
        if (currentComponent.Length > 0)
        {
            var component = parseComponent(currentComponent);
            if (component != null)
            {
                yield return component;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for being a bit late to the party, but I was able to call the Name attribute directly from c#

```
UserPrincipal p
```

and then I was able to call

```
p.Name
```

and that gave me the full name (Common Name)

Sample code:

```
string name;
foreach(UserPrincipal p in PSR)
{
     //PSR refers to PrincipalSearchResult
     name = p.Name;
     Console.WriteLine(name); 
 }
```

Obviously, you will have to fill in the blanks. But this should be easier than parsing regex.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know and haven't checked ;(

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just retrieve the CN attribute values?

As you correctly note, use someone else's class as there are lots of fun edge cases (escaped commas, escaped other characters) that make parsing a DN look easy, but actually reasonably tricky.

I usually use a Java class that comes with the Novell (Now NetID) Identity Manager.  So that is not helpful.

Comment: No can't get the attribute value from an LDAP entry - just have the certificate to work with. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @swisstony: Ah, you have a Cert DN.  That is still the same basic issue, of proper parsing.

Comment: Yes, still a DN so same issue. It's looking like I may have to use a 3rd party library such as bouncycastle...

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Linq; 

var dn = "CN=Jeff Smith,OU=Sales,DC=Fabrikam,DC=COM";
var cn = dn.Split(',').Where(i => i.Contains("CN=")).Select(i => i.Replace("CN=", "")).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: RDN parts can contain escaped commas in form `\,`, so your initial split does not work. Also there may be spaces between parts that you have to remove.

Comment: @picrap While that's true, it is a crude and fast way to get that. And it is good enough in many cases

Answer (score 0):

Well, Here I am another person late to the party. Here is my Solution:

```
var dn = new X500DistinguishedName("CN=TestGroup,OU=Groups,OU=UT-SLC,OU=US,DC=\"Company, inc\",DC=com");
foreach(var part in dn.Format(true).Split("\r\n"))
{
    if(part == "") continue;
    var parts = part.Split('=', 2);
    var key = parts[0];
    var value = parts[1];
    // use your key and value as you see fit here.
}
```

Basically its leveraging the X500DistinguishedName.Format method to put things on lines. Then split by lines, then split each line into key value.

Comment: Have you considered equal signs in quoted parts? Or escaped equal signs?