# How to extract the Email from a X509 Certificate in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, x509certificate, asn.1

I'm looking for the way to get the Email (string) from X509 Certificate. 
I can't find ready property or method for this. So the best for me (most flexible for future tasks) is to get the value by ASN OID (1.2.840.113549.1.9.1). How can I do this using native .NET class?

I tried to use `AsnEncodedData.format` but without any effect. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The example on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509nametype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) might help?

Comment: Thanks! That's it! But what could you suggest about the other solution (get any extension like Email by corresponding OID)?

Comment: Sorry I've got no experience of this area, just good with google and you had no other commenters/answers :)

Comment: It is not possible via built-in tools. You will have to look for 3rd party libraries. But thanks for the idea, it is really worth to consider.

Comment: Thanks, CryptoGuy! It will save me a lot of time! And for the last question, what 3rd party library do you prefere? Is there any alternatives to BouncyCastle that is not well documented?

Comment: @Bridge thank you. I don't have experience in this area, but it seems that  x509.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.EmailName, false) is what I was looking for.

Comment: Related: [Extract Common Name from Distinguished Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688445/extract-common-name-from-distinguished-name)

Answer (score 1):

If it is ok to use 3rd party tools, then you may look at my [Powershell PKI](https://pspki.codeplex.com/) module. This module contains a PKI.Core.dll library which is a set of API. APIs are fairly well documented in the [Library documentation](http://pkix2.sysadmins.lv/library/html/R_Project_Documentation.htm)

With thid library I would go with the following static method and custom class:

```
using PKI.ASN;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;

namespace MyNamespace {
    public class RdnAttribute {
        public Oid OID { get; set; }
        public String Value { get; set; }
    }
    public class MyClass {
        public static List<RdnAttribute> GetRdnAttributes(X500DistinguishedName name) {
            List<RdnAttribute> retValue = new List<RdnAttribute>();
            ASN1 asn = new ASN1(name.RawData);
            asn.MoveNext();
            do {
                ASN1 asn2 = new ASN1(asn.Payload);
                asn2.MoveNext();
                List<Byte> oidRawData = new List<Byte>(asn2.Header);
                oidRawData.AddRange(asn2.Payload);
                Oid oid = ASN1.DecodeObjectIdentifier(oidRawData.ToArray());
                asn2.MoveNext();
                String value;
                switch (asn2.Tag) {
                    case (Byte)ASN1Tags.UniversalString:
                        value = Encoding.UTF32.GetString(asn2.Payload);
                        break;
                    case (Byte)ASN1Tags.BMPString:
                        value = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(asn2.Payload);
                        break;
                    default:
                        value = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(asn2.Payload);
                        break;
                }
                retValue.Add(new RdnAttribute { OID = oid, Value = value });
            } while (asn.MoveNextCurrentLevel());
            return retValue;
        }
    }
}
```

The method returns an array (unordered) of RDN attributes, where `OID` property contains RDN object identifier and `Value` property contains RDN text value. If you can use Linq, then you can quickly search through collection: `somearray.Where(x => x.OID.Value == "1.2.840.113549.1.9.1");`. Note that particular RDN attributes may appear multiple times, therefore you should not use `First*` or `Single*` Linq methods.