# Split Field in a Linq Query

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, linq, split

Below is the content of a field name OULocationPath.  I need to parse out the OU=location but only the "location". Not the "OU=".

***CN=my name,OU=department,OU=location,OU=general area,DC=company,DC=org***

Below is the query that I use to populate a grid.  I haven't added the field above as of yet.

```
  Public Function GetLocationList() As List(Of Contact)
    GetLocationList = mContacts.FindAll(Function(x) x.Company.Contains("CompanyName") = True And x.WorkEmail = Nothing And x.WorkPhone <> "")
End Function
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do the answers to [Extract Common Name from Distinguished Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688445/extract-common-name-from-distinguished-name) help?

Comment: Or maybe you only need something like `Dim ous = OULocationPath.Split({","c}).Where(Function(p) p.StartsWith("OU=")).Select(Function(q) q.Substring(q.IndexOf("=") + 1))`, although that won't cope with escaped commas.

Comment: Don't use `= True`. What does parse out the "location" mean in the context of returning a `List(Of Contact)`? What does it have to do with the method shown?

Comment: In addition to the part of NetMage's comment regarding not needing `= True`, it is better to use `AndAlso` instead of `And` for logic, and to compare to `Nothing` use the `Is` operator, like: `GetLocationList = mContacts.FindAll(Function(x) x.Company.Contains("CompanyName") AndAlso x.WorkEmail Is Nothing AndAlso x.WorkPhone <> "")` - but looking at the parts of that, I wonder if it should be `IsNot Nothing`.

Comment: Andrew Morton and NetMage, thank you for your quick responses. Let me check out your suggestions and I will let you know how I make out. I probably won't be able to try until Tuesday, 27th. I can't wait to get back to this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Andrew Morton and @NetMage,
I was able to get the parse working using the code below:

```
 Public Function GetLocationList() As List(Of Contact)
    GetLocationList = Nothing
    Dim Answerset = mContacts.FindAll(Function(x) x.Company.Contains("CompanyName") = True AndAlso x.WorkEmail = Nothing AndAlso x.WorkPhone IsNot Nothing)
    Dim _GridLocations As New List(Of Contact)
    Dim _GridLocation As Contact
    _GridLocations.Clear()

    For Each l In Answerset
        _GridLocation = New Contact
        With _GridLocation
            .FullName = l.FullName
            .WorkPhone = l.WorkPhone
            .Extension = l.Extension

            Dim s As String = l.OULocationPath
            Dim sp As String() = s.Split(New [Char]() {","c, "="c})
            Dim first6 As String() = sp.ToList().GetRange(0, 6).ToArray()
            .OULocationPath= first6(5)
        End With
        _GridLocations.Add(_GridLocation)
    Next
    GetLocationList = _GridLocations
End Function
```

Comment: Still has the `= True`. The result of `Contains()` is _already a boolean value_. Also, `.Clear()` is not needed on list that was just created a line earlier.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn, thank you for the info.  I will update it on my program.