# Check if String contains the key

Tags: c#, linq

There is a string that has the following key value pair. It is being Seperated by ","  So after splitting it by.

```
 string[] strSubject = certificate.Subject.Split(',');

            [0] "E=ankurda@aol.com" 
        [1] " CN=Ankur" 
        [2] " OU=Telco" 
        [3] " O=aol"    
        [4] " L=Mum"    
        [5] " S=Mh"
        [6] " C=IN"
```

the value is a combination of key value pair, With key name fixed. The problem is it is not mandatory to have all the keys for all objects . 
what it meant is for some object it will have some values, for Example

```
            [0] "E=ankurda@aol.com" 
        [1] " CN=Ankur" 
        [2] " S=Mh"
        [3] " C=IN"
```

So I cant hard code the Index and fetch the value by doing some thing like this

```
String value = strSubject[5].Replace("S=",string.Empty));
```

I have tried using .contains too like this

```
if (strSubject.Contains("C="))//Don't Know the value part as it is dynamic
   {
//this does not work
   }
```

How can I get the values of the keys that are present after splitting . Can Linq query fetch the value not sure about it.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Find if there's an entry with the key `S`? Obtain its value? You've jumped into your attempted solutions without really telling us what the problem is that you're trying to solve.

Comment: check if this might help you, it parses keyvaluepairs

http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2124-how-to-parse-keyvalue-pairs-in-c/

Comment: why not you are using Hashtable for storing key/value pairs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a dictionary and query that:

```
var testStr = "E=foo,B=Bar,O=aol,FAIL";

var dict = testStr.Split(',').Where(x => x.Contains("="))
   .Select(x => x.Trim().Split('=')).ToDictionary(x => x[0], x=> x[1]);

dict.ContainsKey("theKey");
```

(This also gives you a convenient way of handle the queries.)

Comment: Looking at the OP's data, I'd suggest also adding a Trim() operation after the initial Split(), as it appears that some of the keyvalue pairs may have whitespace after the separating comma.

Comment: it is working but it is adding a space in the start of the key, Can we remove the space since for checking  so it is coming some thing like dict.ContainsKey(" C") it should be dict.ContainsKey("C")

Comment: The heading space problem should be fixed by the update I made 7 mins ago.

Comment: This will break if the value contains a comma, or if you pass a value with identical key names (several "OU"'s are common in distinguished names). I added a separate answer with suggested resources.

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is to parse the string into something like `Dictionary<string, string>`, it will be much easier to work with that.

Something like (assuming the space after `,` is required):

```
var subjectDictionary = certificate.Subject
    .Split(new[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.None)
    .Select(pair => pair.Split('='))
    .ToDictionary(pair => pair[0], pair => pair[1])

if (subjectDictionary.ContainsKey("C"))
{
   var valueForC = subjectDictionary["C"];
   …
}
```

Comment: +1 for the use of ToDictionary()... I was going to edit my answer. But this is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I guess something like this should work..

```
string[] strSubject = certificate.Subject.Split(',');
for (int i = 0; i < strSubject.Length; i++)
{
   string[] row = strSubject[i].Split('=');

   switch (row[0]) // the key
   {
        case "E": 
            // do something, value is stored in row[1]
            break;
        case "CN":
            // do something else
            break;
        //... cover the expected keys
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the `yourWord.IndexOf(inputString) != 0`

So using `System.Linq`

```
var match = yourWords.ToList().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ToLower().IndexOf(inputString) != 0);
```

But there are loads of ways of other ways doing this. Pick your fave!

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=0;i<strSubject.Length;i++)
{
      if(strSubject[i].Trim().StartsWith("C="))
      {
               //perform your action
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try get all the key and values:

```
var q = certificate.Subject.Split(',')
    .Select(x => x.Trim())
    .Select(x => new
    {
        key = x.Substring(0, x.IndexOf('=')).Trim(),
        value = x.Substring(x.IndexOf('=') + 1).Trim()
    });
```

then:

```
foreach (var x in q)
{
    if (x.key == "C")
    {
        // code
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than adding the second block of the foreach... why not add a where clause to the first linq query?

Comment: I think he need all the key/value, at least it's what i understand.

Comment: I thought maybe they were only spliting for the sake of the search. But yes, I you want the whole list then yes... Maybe use .ToDictionary() then rather than the select?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly is your aim, but what if you do a Split again with '=' as a separator:

```
string[] strParts = theValue.Split("=");
```

Than you have the key and the value in `strParts[0]` and `strParts[1]` respectively.

Comment: More detailed in see walther's solution. I thought something similar to that.

Answer (score 0):

To get the values just use this line of code:

```
var values = strSubject.Select(v => v.Split('=')[1]);
```

And for key *and* value:

```
var values = strSubject.Select(v => new { Key = v.Split('=')[0], Value = v.Split('=')[1] });
```

Answer (score 0):

Parsing distinguished names can be challenging. I suggest you consider Hall72215's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433383/net-ldap-paths-utilities-c), or [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9788/An-RFC-2253-Compliant-Distinguished-Name-Parser) project on code project for a solution in managed code.

The accepted answer by faester will break if you have RDNs with the same name which is quite common for distinguished names. For example this certificate from Verisign:

```
OU = NO LIABILITY ACCEPTED, (c)97 VeriSign, Inc., OU = VeriSign Time Stamping Service, Root OU = VeriSign, Inc., O = VeriSign Trust Network
```

Here you have two occurences of OU, and one of the OU values contains a comma which will also break the code.