# Reading a string from and to a certain character

Tags: c#, string

I would like to know if it is possible to read a certain string of n-length, from x character to y character without having to split it into smaller pieces.

I have the following string, for a path in AD `CN=someName,OU=someGroup,OU=groups,DC=some,DC=domain,DC=com`, and I would like to be able to just read the `someName` part of it, without splitting by `=` or `,` first. How do I achieve that?

Reason is, that I do not have to do group comparison as I am doing it right now:

```
SearchResult t1 = search.FindOne();
foreach (string s in t1.Properties["memberof"])
{
    foreach (string g in groups)
    {
        if (s.ToLower().Contains(g.ToLower()))
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

I would rather make the if clause to equals, but I do not want to always split the above path/groups into an array twice. How do I do that?

Comment: _"I do not have to do group comparison"_ I dont get it, what is `groups`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I am comparing if a certain user is in a certain group, to check for rights, `groups` is an array of groups that are valid. Also, as I said, I would like to avoid using arrays if possible, and I'm relatively new to programming, so I do not know all the syntax, for example LINQ, etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using simple string manipulation with `IndexOf` and `Substring`:

```
string s = "CN=someName,OU=someGroup,OU=groups,DC=some,DC=domain,DC=com";

const string prefix = "CN=";
int start = s.IndexOf(prefix);
if (start >= 0)
{
    string value = s.Substring(start + prefix.Length, s.IndexOf(',', start) - prefix.Length);
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Note that this simple example would fail *if* the `CN=` entry was the last in the line (since it’s not terminated by a comma). You could check that first by looking at the return value of the second `IndexOf` call though.

But in this case, `CN=` will usually be the first thing anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing group comparisons I would use System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace

```
PrincipalContext Context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "");
UserPrincipal Usr = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(Context, "User");
GroupPrincipal G = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(Context, "Group");

if(Usr.IsMemberOf(G)) {

}
```

Comment: This would work, but it breaks if there are groups in the array of allowed groups, which do not exist in the AD yet. Any way to circumvent this?

Answer (score 0):

With `Split` you can check if **any** of the given keys equals to the search value.

```
var val = "CN=someName,OU=someGroup,OU=groups,DC=some,DC=domain,DC=com";
var prefix = "CN";
var searchValue = "someName";
var contains = val.Split(',').Any(value => value.Split('=')[0] == prefix && value.Split('=')[1] == searchValue);
```

Insead of checking if the value is equal to the search value you can also just return the value.

```
var val = "CN=someName,OU=someGroup,OU=groups,DC=some,DC=domain,DC=com";
var prefix = "CN";
var foundValue = val.Split(',').FirstOrDefault(value => value.Split('=')[0] == prefix)?.Split('=')[1];
```

I still used `Split` despite you said you don't want to use it as I think it makes a nice one liner.

Comment: I want to only look at the `"CN="` prefix, since that is where the group names come from, but thank you

Comment: @EInherjar Ive changed the code that it looks for the `CN=` prefix. Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: @EInherjar and this solution works wherever the cn is in the string.

Comment: Sorry, by keys you meant OU, DC and such, or just everything between `CN=` and `,`?

Comment: @EInherjar I meant `OU` or `DC` or `CN`. And the searchValue is what should match beteen the `=` and `,` or the end of the string.

Comment: How would it work to look only for the value between the `"CN="` and the `","`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.IndexOf` to find the correct offset, then use `String.SubString` to read the part you want.

```
const string input = "CN=someName,OU=someGroup,OU=groups,DC=some,DC=domain,DC=com";
const string start = "CN=";
const string stop = ",";

int startIndex = input.IndexOf(start, 0);
int stopIndex = input.IndexOf(stop, startIndex);

var extracted = input.Substring(startIndex + start.Length, stopIndex - startIndex - start.Length);

Console.WriteLine(extracted);
```

[.net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/N0dRFZ)

PS: maybe also take a look at [Is there a .NET class that can parse CN= strings out of LDAP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833785/is-there-a-net-class-that-can-parse-cn-strings-out-of-ldap) for your special usecase!