# Improve RegEx search

Tags: c#, regex

Using DirectoryServices.AccountManagement I'm getting users `DistinguishedName` which looks like so:

```
CN=Adam West,OU=STORE,OU=COMPANY,DC=mycompany,DC=group,DC=eu
```

I need to get first `OU` value from this.
I found similar solution: [C# Extracting a name from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356480/c-sharp-extracting-a-name-from-a-string)

And using some tweaks I created this code:

```
string input = @"CN=Adam West,OU=STORE,OU=COMPANY,DC=mycompany,DC=group,DC=eu";
Match m = Regex.Match(input, @"OU=([a-zA-Z\\]+)\,.*$");
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
```

This code returns `STORE` as expected, but if I change `Groups[1]` to `Groups[0]` I get almost same result as input string:

```
OU=STORE,OU=COMPANY,DC=mycompany,DC=group,DC=eu
```

How can I change this regex so it will return only values of `OU`? SO that in this example I get array of 2 matches. If I would have more OU in my string then array would be longer.

**EDIT:**
I've converted my code (using @dasblinkenlight suggestions) into function:

```
private static List<string> GetOUs()
{
    var input = @"CN=Adam West,OU=STORE,OU=COMPANY,DC=mycompany,DC=group,DC=eu";
    var mm = Regex.Matches(input, @"OU=([a-zA-Z\\]+)");
    return (from Match m in mm select m.Groups[1].Value).ToList();
}
```

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression is fine (almost), you are just using a wrong API.

Remove the parts of the regexp that match up to the ending anchor `$`, and change the call of `Match` for a call of `Matches`, and get the matches in a loop, like this:

```
var input = @"CN=Adam West,OU=STORE,OU=COMPANY,DC=mycompany,DC=group,DC=eu";
var mm = Regex.Matches(input, @"OU=([a-zA-Z\\]+)");
foreach (Match m in mm)
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Comment: I've updated my question and turned my code into function. Could You please take a look at it?

Comment: @Misiu Yes, the change is correct. You can reduce the `res` variable, and return the expression that you assign to it instead, like this: `return (from Match m in mm select m.Groups[1].Value).ToList();`

Comment: Thanks! :) Is it possible to get only first value of `OU` simper? Now I get all OU groups and must do `[0]`, but maybe I can get first OU faster and easier?

Comment: @Misiu If all you need is the first `OU`, you can search for the `"OU="` string, then search for the `","` from the location where you found the `"OU="`, and finally take a substring between the two indexes, [like this](http://ideone.com/qTL5fU). This will be faster than a regex, but obviously this solution is less powerful.

Answer (score 1):

Your existing regex:

```
@"OU=([a-zA-Z\\]+)\,.*$"
```

Matches `OU=`, then some letters and backslashes (`[a-zA-Z\\]+`), then a comma, then any characters (`.*`) to the end of the line (`$`).

Thus a single match will always match the entire line after the first `OU` section.

Modify your regex by removing the `,.*$` at the end, at it will match each OU group:

```
@"OU=([a-zA-Z\\]+)"
```

Also note that the parentheses are a capturing group.  They are useful if you also want to capture just the value part by itself, but if you are not using that, they are not necessary, and you can just have this:

```
@"OU=[a-zA-Z\\]+"
```

Comment: if I do `Regex.Match(input, @"OU=([a-zA-Z\\]+)");` and then select group[0] I get `OU=STORE` instead of `STORE`

Answer (score 0):

It's beacuse you are mixing up matches and groups

```
string input = @"CN=Adam West,OU=STORE,OU=COMPANY,DC=mycompany,DC=group,DC=eu";
MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(input, @"OU=([a-zA-Z\\]+),");

foreach(Match m in mc)
{
  Console.WriteLine(m.Result("$1"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Group[0]` returns the full match:
`Group[1]` returns the first Pattern in the match [i.e. everything in the first parenthesis '('  ')'  ]

So if you wanted to get exactly those 2 occurances of OU.. you could do this:

```
 Match m = Regex.Match(input, @"OU=([a-zA-Z\\]+)\,OU=([a-zA-Z\\]+)\,.*$");
 Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
 Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[2].Value);
```

`Group[0]` returns the full match: (which you don't want)
`Group[1]` returns the first Pattern in the match [i.e everything in the first parenthesis '('  ')'  ]
`Group[2]` returns the second Pattern in the match [i.e. everything in the second parenthesis '('  ')'  ]

Giving: 
STORE
COMPANY

But I'm assuming you don't want to be so explicit with your Regex for each Pattern you are interested in.
If you want to get multiple matches, then you need to do Regex's Matches call that returns a Matchcollection.

```
MatchCollection ms = Regex.Matches(...);
```

This still won't work with your current Regex though, because everything from `STORE` so the end of the line will be in the first match. If you only want to get the pattern "1-or-more-letters" after a "OU="

You only need:

```
@"OU=([a-zA-Z\\]+)"
```

So your code would be:

```
string input = @"CN=Adam West,OU=STORE,OU=COMPANY,DC=mycompany,DC=group,DC=eu";
MatchCollection ms = Regex.Matches(input, @"OU=([a-zA-Z\\]+)");

foreach (Match m in ms)
{
   Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);// get the string in the first "(" ")"
}
```